# Multipage form using itext with Acrofield and Dynamic table

Tags: pdf, dynamic, itext

I'm  new at working with itext and I'm looking for help.

I'm creating a PDF document based on a PDF template which contains a form with acrofields. This form is composed by some fields on top page and a table and has only one page.

The PDF document generated will have one or more pages depending on table's size (if size content extends predefined size, table should continue in the second page). Also every page should display fields on the top with the same information.

I've tried to solve it following "AddExtraTable" example, but I didn't get to keep the fields on top in all pages, only in the first one.

I've tried also to solve it with PdfCopy. This approach displays the fields on top in all pages but table content is not properly displayed.

Can someone help me?

PS: I have to use itext 2.1.7 because of project requirements.

Comment: Please show your pivotal code. From your description alone I don't really understand what you tried and what eventually failed.

Comment: Your project requirements are to use an obsolete version of a PDF library? If I were you, I'd walk away from such a project. There are enough IT jobs available where you can use more recent versions.

Comment: what Bruno writes. A requirement to use a version of a library that is 7 years old, while there is a version less than 2 months old, is a huuuuuuuge red flag. If you want to be a software craftsman, you do not let your customer or employer dictate you such nonsense. Run away as fast as you can!

Comment: Yes, I agree but I can't do anything, it's an ancient application. I'm sorry...

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well. The example that I used was "AddExtraPage.java", like you can see here [link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/repeating-parts-form).  In this example, it's used "stationery.pdf" as resource and this pdf has some fields like "to", "from", "date" and "footer". I need the same result that "more_than_one_page.pdf" but I need that fields "to", "from" and "date" are  published in all pages. I hope it's clear now. Thanks you very much again.